# is there any unique SQL function to retrieve only year and month from the timestamp and based on that result i need to find out the earliest made

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I TRIED THE BELOW MENTIONED CODE BUT IT GIVING DIFFERENT ANSWERS
CODE USED

```
 $SELECT  MIN(DATENAME(MM,orders.occurred_at)) AS 'Month',
            MIN(DATENAME(YY,orders.occurred_at)) AS 'Year'
    FROM orders
```

TABLE

```
id  account_id  occurred_at
1   1001    2015-10-06 17:31:14.000
2   1001    2015-11-05 03:34:33.000
3   1001    2015-12-04 04:21:55.000
4   1001    2016-01-02 01:18:24.000
5   1001    2016-02-01 19:27:27.000
6   1001    2016-03-02 15:29:32.000
7   1001    2016-04-01 11:20:18.000
8   1001    2016-05-01 15:55:51.000
9   1001    2016-05-31 21:22:48.000
10  1001    2016-06-30 12:32:05.000
11  1001    2016-07-30 03:26:30.000
12  1001    2016-08-28 07:13:39.000
13  1001    2016-09-26 23:28:25.000
14  1001    2016-10-26 20:31:30.000
15  1001    2016-11-25 23:21:32.000
16  1001    2016-12-24 05:53:13.000
17  1011    2016-12-21 10:59:34.000
18  1021    2015-10-12 02:21:56.000
19  1021    2015-11-11 07:37:01.000
20  1021    2015-12-11 16:53:18.000
```

Comment: If you format your data so that it is readable and include the output you expect based on that sample data, someone might attempt to help. To extract year and month parts of a date, have a look in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Find the minimum before extracting the parts. So the `min()` will be the argument/inside the other functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help@shawnt00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand if you want to see all of the results and just sort them so that the earliest instance would show up first in the list, or if you only want the earliest record by itself.

Sorting the list by the timestamp and displaying the `Month()` and `Year()` from the timestamp is easy enough:

```
SELECT
   ID
  ,Account_ID
  ,Occurred_At
  ,MONTH(Occurred_At) AS Occurred_Month
  ,YEAR(Occurred_At) AS Occurred_Year
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Occurred_At ASC -- This puts the oldest record at the top of the list
;
```

If you only want to retrieve **only** the oldest record, then you could do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 -- This returns only the topmost record
   ID
  ,Account_ID
  ,Occurred_At
  ,MONTH(Occurred_At) AS Occurred_Month
  ,YEAR(Occurred_At) AS Occurred_Year
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Occurred_At ASC  -- This puts the oldest record at the top of the list
;
```

Presumably, you don't need to extract the month and year from Occurred_At in order to know which order was first... The timestamp gives you that information.  But if, for some reason, you want to sort by the month and year instead of the full timestamp:

```
SELECT TOP 1
   ID
  ,Account_ID
--,Occurred_At -- If you don't need this line, you can remove it...
  ,MONTH(Occurred_At) AS Occurred_Month
  ,YEAR(Occurred_At) AS Occurred_Year
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Occurred_Year ASC, Occurred_Month ASC
;
```

Comment: thanks, man this one solved the issue@3BK

Comment: Assuming indexes you'd be better off just sorting my the original column value than two derived values.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes, you are absolutely right, but I gave him the option because it wasn't entirely clear to me if this was what he required for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
    SELECT  MONTH(occurred_at) AS Month,
            YEAR(occurred_at) AS Year
    FROM orders
```

*OR*

```
   SELECT  FORMAT(occurred_at, 'MMMM') AS Month,
            FORMAT(occurred_at, 'yyyy') AS Year
    FROM orders
```

*OR*

```
SELECT  
   FORMAT(occurred_at, 'y') AS 'Month and Year',
FROM orders
```

Comment: Hi @ Nadeesh Hirushan thanks for your time & support